# No such column 'Description' on entity 'Attachment'

Tags: api, soap-api, attachment, error-messages

I am using salesforce partner web service API Version 42.0.

I call description field from attachment object. This attachment is in the custom object I created.

And somehow got this error.

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: INVALID_FIELD: 
ParentId, ContentType, Name, Body, Description FROM attachment where
                                   ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:47
No such column 'Description' on entity 'Attachment'. If you are attempting 
to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field 
name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate 
names.
```

I have tried using this query on my dev console in salesforce and it running fine.

On setup salesforce, I can't find how I can set the permission of this field in attachment object either.